# Find all substrings within a string with overlap

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, substring, overlapping-matches

Hi im trying to find all overlapping substrings in  a string here is my code its only finding nonrepeating ACA.

```
$haystack = "ACAAGACACATGCCACATTGTCC";
$needle = "ACA";
echo preg_match_all("/$needle/", $haystack, $matches);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `echo` to print the return value of `preg_match_all`. That is, you're displaying only the number of matches found. What you probably wanted to do was something like `print_r($matches);`, like this:

```
$haystack = "ACAAGACACATGCCACATTGTCC";
$needle = "ACA";
preg_match_all("/$needle/", $haystack, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ACA
            [1] => ACA
            [2] => ACA
        )

)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/6FhTd)

If your real concern is that it counted `ACACA` only once, well, there are three things that need to be said about that:

1. That's basically unavoidable with regex.
2. You really shouldn't count this twice, as it's overlapping. It's not a true recurrence of the pattern.
3. That said, if you want to count that twice, you could do so with something like this:

   ```
   echo preg_match_all("/(?=$needle)/", $haystack, $matches);
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   4
   ```

   [Demo](https://3v4l.org/TXnCF)

Comment: but I need the overlapping ACA too thats my issue

Comment: //TT occurs  twice  in TTT!

Comment: @lolsharp The `(?=...)` is what's called a "positive look-ahead assertion." It means, "See if what's next is *xyz*, but don't move the cursor." It allows us to find each spot where you have `ACA` (or whatever `$needle` is), without "consuming" those three characters. The next match can be only one character further along.

Answer (score 0):

Here a script to find all occurences of a substring, also the overlapping ones.

```
    $haystack = "ACAAGACACATGCCACATTGTCC";
    $needle   = "ACA";

    $positions    = [];
    $needle_len   = strlen($needle);
    $haystack_len = strlen($haystack);

    for ($i = 0; $i <= $haystack_len; $i++) {
        if( substr(substr($haystack,$i),0,$needle_len) == $needle){
            $positions[]=$i;
        }
    }
    print_r($positions);
```

Output: `Array ( 0, 5, 7, 14 )`